# Remove unnecessary bottom border in Android using Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I want to remove unnecessary **underline** from **textfield**. I am using **Titanium SDK 7.0.2.GA**

There are no properties of TextField such as "**underlineColorAndroid**" or something related.

Did someone face this problem? Help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `backgroundColor:transparent` to remove that border.